# how to force git pull when resolving pull request conflict

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

I have conflicts when trying to merge a pull-request on github where the repo is clonable from `https://github.com/my_production_repo/my_app.git`.

So following their docs, I tried to run this on my local (productio_repo)

```
git checkout -b tmp master
git pull https://github.com/my_forked_repo/my_app.git master
```

Then I have some conflicts to fix. The issue is that some of the conflicts are related to `byte-code files`. I want to force my local files to be overwritten by the files from the `my_forked_repo`, I tried this

```
git merge -s recursive -X theirs https://github.com/my_forked_repo/my_app.git master
```

but I got `https://github.com/my_forked_repo/my_app.git - not something we can merge`

Comment: You're being led astray by `git pull`.  The `pull` command is just a convenience shortcut for two separate commands: `git fetch`, which is what lets you retrieve commits from another repository (such as the fork) into your own repo, and `git merge`, which requires that you work with commits in your own repo.  You cannot provide a URL to `git merge`, only to `git fetch`.

Comment: probably you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35442565/2303202). Note that one is edited for handling whole directory, for single file the first version is better

Answer (score 0):

If its not many files, you can try use `git reset HEAD byte-code.file` on all of them.

And remember you need to commit your changes before merge, maybe then it would work.

Comment: I have even done a git reset hard on all files with no success

Comment: Dunno then, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680711/how-to-do-a-github-pull-request