# How to manage conflicts in generated files

Tags: django, git, merge, internationalization, merge-conflict-resolution

We are using Django and git. We have i18n enabled and run periodically `compilemessages` and `makemessages`. Everybody works in a separate branch and periodically we merge them in `master`. The problem is when two people need to add translations in their branches. Since `compilemessages` effectively changes the `.po` file, git cannot merge them and the second person have to manually resolve conflicts in the translations. We can't ignore `.po` files because translations are important to be in version control system. For now there are two possible ways to deal with the problem:

1. To accumulate translations  first and running `compilemessages` and `makemessages` only at certain times.
2. To make translations only before merge  and be sure to merge the PR with master before running `compilemessages`.

So there are two questions involved:

1. How to manage Django translations in git?
2. And the more general - how to manage machine generated files which **should** stay in version control?

Comment: The most effective solution we've found so far is to only make and compile translations as the last step of our release process, ie in either a hotfix or release branch.

Comment: Does it *change* the .po file or completely *generate* the .po file? If the latter, why keep the .po file in the repository at all? You can easily regenerate them from the source, no?

Comment: You generate the file and add only the needed translations. But `compilemessages` generate new file while comparing it with the older version. All the current translations are kept in the `.po` file and `compilemessages` use them adding only the new ones and checking for fuzzy matches.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35442565/2303202 tl;dr: generate new version of the file during merge conflict resolution.